# PDFDebugger in pdfbox locks up viewing page content stream

Tags: pdfbox

I have an odd PDF that appears to have image data encoded directly into the content stream instead of being tucked away as a resource (there are images in resources but they're not actually in the page for some reason). The actual page's content length is very large (107,988,275).

[image: page contents]

It's killing our servers so I thought I'd crack open the PDFDebugger to see what is in the content stream. When I open the PDF and navigate to the content stream, it just locks up completely. I've tried increasing the heap size (4g) and it didn't seem to help.

Is there a way I can view just the head of the stream? I'd really love to know what is in this thing. Is there a way of encoding image data directly into a page's content stream?

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot due to legal concerns

Comment: To mitigate our performance issue, I've just rejected processing if the page has a content stream that is too large but I'm really curious about this thing.

Comment: Well, inline images have always been an alternative to image resources. But they always have been a bit brittle. Meanwhile (ISO 32000-2) inline images are recommended to be used for small images only (<4KB).

Comment: Is there any way to detect large inline images via pdfbox? Right now, I'm just rejecting the document if the page's content stream length is too large but that seems a little aggressive.

Comment: You can parse the content stream and check the image related events. I assume, though, that this might not be about large online images but about images for which the end is not clearly located.

Comment: You could try to access the page content stream with `PDPage.getContents()` and then copy this into a file. Open it with an editor like NOTEPAD++. Look at what's in this file... inline images start with BI, actual image starts with ID, and ends with EI. See PDF specification, annex A "operator summary", that is a good start.

Comment: OK... so, get ready for this. It's not inline images. It's a HUGE diagram drawn with moveto and lineto operators. Poor man's SVG I suppose. Not sure what to do with this but thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tilman suggested in the comments, you can view the content stream by writing the InputStream given by PDPage.getContents() to a file.